# Examples of classifying spaces of monoids

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, monoid, classifying-spaces

**Definition.** The **classifying space** functor for monoids is the functor $|{-}|\colon\mathsf{Mon}\to\mathsf{Top}$ defined as the composition
$$
\mathsf{Mon}
\xrightarrow{\mathbf{B}}
\mathsf{Cats}
\xrightarrow{\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}}
\mathsf{sSets}
\xrightarrow{|-|}
\mathsf{Top},
$$
where

- $\mathbf{B}$ is the [delooping functor for monoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping);
- $\mathrm{N}_{\bullet}$ is the [nerve functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve);
- $|{-}|$ is the [geometric realisation functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+realization).

---

**Examples.** So far, I've found the following:

1. The classifying space of the additive monoid of natural numbers is homotopic to the circle, i.e. $|\mathbb{N}|\simeq S^{1}$ ([proof](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94017)).
2. We have $|\mathbb{Z}|\simeq|\mathbb{N}|\simeq S^1$ also.
3. More generally, we have $|\mathbb{N}^{\oplus n}|\simeq|\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus n}|\simeq (S^1)^{\times n}$, the $n$-torus $\mathbf{T}^{n}$.
4. (For examples involving groups; see [MO 56363](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56363).)

**Question.** What are other examples? In particular, what are the classifying spaces of the following monoids?

- The multiplicative monoid $(\mathbb{N},\cdot,1)$ of natural numbers;
- The multiplicative monoid $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot,1)$ of integers;
- <s>The free monoid on a set $S$;</s> by [Proposition 4.4.1 of Lenz](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/lenzmaster.pdf), if a monoid $A$ is free, then $|A|\simeq|A^\mathrm{grp}|$, and hence the classifying space of the free monoid $F_n$ on $n$ elements will be homotopy equivalent to the classifying space of the free *group* on $n$ elements, which is the wedge $S^1\vee\cdots\vee S^1$ of $n$ circles.

Comment: There is a result to the effect that every connected CW complex is homotopy equivalent to the classifying space of some monoid.

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we have $\mathbb{N}^\times \cong \bigoplus_p \mathbb{N}$, where the sum is taken over all primes.  And $\mathbb{Z}^\times \cong \{\pm 1\} \times \mathbb{N}^\times$.